Simplify $\nabla_{\nabla_{[W,X]}Y-\nabla_W\nabla_XY+\nabla_X\nabla_WY}Z[f]$
I'm trying to simplify the formula as in the title. I know that
$$R(W,X,Y,Z)=\langle\nabla_{[W,X]}Y-\nabla_W\nabla_XY+\nabla_X\nabla_WY,Z\rangle$$
by the definition. Then I may conclude that $$\left(\nabla_{[W,X]}Y-\nabla_W\nabla_XY+\nabla_X\nabla_WY\right)Z[f]=R(W,X,Y,Z)[f].$$ But as you see, it is definitely different from what is in the title. Now I wonder if I can continue simplify this formula.

You can't use the formula for $R(W,X,Y,Z)$. Use the formula for $R(W,X)Y$.

It is unclear what you mean by $Z\,.$ Riemann eats three vector fields $W,X,Y$ and
returns a vector field. Then it cannot eat a fourth one $Z\,.$ However the expression in the title is legit when $Z$ is a vector field.
I am not very sure what counts as a simplification. Perhaps this:
$$\tag1
R^\mu{}_{\nu\rho\sigma}W^\nu X^\rho Y^\sigma
$$
are the components of the vector field $R(W,X,Y)\,.$ If we denote the expression (1) by $U^\mu$ then we have a vector field $U$ with those components and what is in the title is
$$
(\nabla_UZ)[f]=(U^\mu\nabla_\mu Z^\nu)(\partial_\nu f)\,.
$$
